# Fragment over Fragment issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

My requirement is :

In one Fragment, had `textview`, by clicking on that one `DialogFragment` is appearing with a list of values. By clicking on value, The dialog fragment should be closed and selected values should be displayed in `textview` in the first fragment.

But here the problem is accessing `textview` object is **null.**

Communicating between fragments using interface  i.e., By clicking on list in `dialogFragment` one interface is calling. That interface method implemented in first fragment.

So, How to access the `textview` object?

Here code is:

```
FragmentManager manger = getFragmentManager();
listDialogFragment.show(manger, null);

public interface onOkClickListener {
    void setOnOkClickListener(int pos,String selectedID,MainActivity actv);
}

@Override
public void setOnOkClickListener(int pos,String id,MainActivity actv) {      
    textView object// accessing null
}
```

Thanks In advance..

Comment: if that interface is implemented in the first fragment why can't you access the textView from that method?

Comment: Hey Dude! I dont know...

Comment: you have an interface and that interface has a method. now write the code to change the textView text inside that method.

Comment: Accessing the textview object is getting null inside the method..., I dont know why it is happening?

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Please look at sample code which i edited in question

Comment: could you post complete fragment1 and fragment2 classes please?

Comment: I gave sample context Which is same to actual requirement of project. So, lot of unnecessary code is there relative this context..

Comment: Can't able to answer without the fragment1 and fragment2 source code in full.